# «Как бы грустно не звучало, но я сегодня...»(.) Найдите в этом отрывке из переписки одну орфогр. ошибку

Tags: точка

Нужна ли эта точка в моём сообщении?

> «Как бы грустно не звучало, но я сегодня...»(.) Найдите в этом отрывке из переписки одну орфогр. ошибку.

Comment: _Н**и**_ звучало, а не _н**е**_ звучало.

Comment: @Максим  Вы исправили ошибку, и сообщение потеряло смысл.

Comment: Действительно. Зачем надо было исправлять ошибку? Лучше вообще закрыть вопрос.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не имеет никакого смысла отвечать на данный вопрос.

Comment: Не надо закрывать! Максим!

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Я не собирался закрывать. Что-то тупанул, изменив сообщение. Я думал, вы ошиблись, а это я слепой.

Comment: Цитирование по образцу прямой речи:  ставится многоточие, а точка не нужна.