# Как выбрать варианты "как бы ни" и "как бы не" (4 разных значения)

Tags: орфография, частица-не, не-или-ни, ни

В некоторых случаях предложения  со значением усиления или отрицания имеют **сходную структуру**, и тогда **выбор НИ или НЕ** особенно затруднителен.  Вопрос задан под впечатлением **[от темы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478490/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8)**.

**Дополнительное пояснение**

В этих примерах надо различать варианты:

***КАК БЫ НИ*** — уступительное значение,

***КАК БЫ НЕ*** — уподобление,

***КАК БЫ НЕ*** — опасение.

Кроме того, в одном из предложений использован союз ***КАК БЫ НЕ*** как аналог ***КАБЫ НЕ*** (то есть ***ЕСЛИ БЫ НЕ*** с условным значением), но не в разговорном стиле, а в книжном устаревшем (это мое предположение). Ведь союз КАБЫ состоит из  КАК + БЫ

[Значение словосочетания «как бы не»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B1%D1%8B+%D0%BD%D0%B5)

**Миниатюра «Красноречивый дворянин»**

(1) **Как бы н...** хотел  я приехать, то разве поспешил бы сделать это при первой возможности.

(2) **Как бы н...** хотелось мне увидеть вас, но что поделаешь, мы ведь не принадлежим только самим себе.

(3) **Как бы н...** сомневались вы во мне, но хотя бы на этот раз прошу вас поверить в мою искренность.

(4) **Как бы н...** пришлось мне уехать раньше, и в  этом мои опасения, но я все-таки постараюсь подольше оставаться у вас.

(5)  И давайте забудем тот разговор, **как бы и н...** говорил я вам ничего вовсе и  **как бы н...** трудно вам это сделать.

Пожалуйста, помогите **правильно** выбрать НЕ и НИ в этих предложениях. У меня есть ответы, но мне хотелось бы их **проверить**.

Comment: Ваши вопросы всегда очень интересны. Но скажу честно. Отвечать на этот вопрос я не хотел лишь потому, что ответ на него вы и сами прекрасно знаете. Впрочем, как и почти на все ваши вопросы. Я даже не сомневаюсь. Но я ответил потому, чтобы и другие знали ответ.

Comment: Кстати, можно вам написать на почту?

Comment: Мне показалась интересной эта тема. Значение КАК БЫ НЕ не часто применяется, а вариант, как  мне кажется, заслуживает  внимания. Это не только грамматика, но и история языка.  Разве не интересно представить, как говорили люди, к примеру, в XVIII веке?  Поэтому я не понимаю вашего нежелания  отвечать на этот вопрос, а также на другие мои вопросы.

Comment: Ну я же написал. Вы прекрасно разбираетесь в теме своих вопросов. А так все интересно. Повторюсь: ваши вопросы всегда очень интересны.,

Comment: 4 значения: уступка, условие, уподобление, опасение. Кто автор миниатюры? А вы догадайтесь)

Comment: Уж не случайно один из наших участников?

Comment: Все может быть.  Сохраним интригу... )

Comment: Все понятно...)

Comment: Вы не ответили на мой вопрос. См.выше.

Comment: Да, я понял уже (КАБЫ НЕ) и стёр сообщение. А автор – вы! Ссылку, пжлста!

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец, вы думаете, автор –  Sharon?

Comment: @Серж, думаю, да.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. *Как бы н**е** хотел я приехать, то разве поспешил бы сделать это при первой возможности.*
2. *Как бы н**и** хотелось мне увидеть вас, но что поделаешь, мы ведь не принадлежим только самим себе.*
3. *Как бы н**и** сомневались вы во мне, но хотя бы на этот раз прошу вас поверить в мою искренность.*
4. *Как бы н**е** пришлось мне уехать раньше, и в этом мои опасения, но я все-таки постараюсь подольше оставаться у вас.*
5. *И давайте забудем тот разговор, как бы и н**е** говорил я вам ничего вовсе и как бы н**и** трудно вам это сделать.*

Comment: Прекрасно! Вопрос ваш, я принимаю   ответ. Но позже дам пояснения нашему новому участнику,  В том ответе мне понравился интерес  к этой теме, как и к языку вообще.

Answer (score 3):

**Ответ на комментарии**

**Спасибо** всем за ответы и за участие в обсуждении. Отдельно благодарю автора **первого ответа** за подробный разбор темы. Там допущена только одна неточность, и это очень хороший результат!

1. Я же хотела остановиться на некоторых **особенностях приведенных предложений.**

(1) ***Как бы (если бы) не** хотел я приехать, то разве поспешил бы сделать это при первой возможности.*

**КАК БЫ НЕ** (соврем. разг. **КАБЫ НЕ**) имеет значения **условия,** но такую форму сложно найти в источниках, так что можно вообще сомневаться в ее существовании. Но я хорошо  чувствую это условное значение **по грамматике предложения**, и оно дает нам возможность услышать старинную русскую речь, будто бы перенестись в ту эпоху.

(2) ***Как бы ни** хотелось мне увидеть вас, но что поделаешь, мы ведь не принадлежим только самим себе.*

(3) **Как бы ни** сомневались вы во мне, но хотя бы на этот раз прошу вас поверить в мою искренность.

Это два предложения со значением **уступки**:  форма знакомая, так что никто не ошибся.

(4) **Как бы не** пришлось мне уехать раньше, и в этом мои опасения, но я все-таки постараюсь подольше оставаться у вас.

Значение **опасения** указано в: «Толковом словаре русского языка» под редакцией **Д. Н. Ушакова (1935-1940),** тоже не очень современный стиль. Это значение тоже нужно услышать и отличить от **уподобления.**

(5) И давайте забудем тот разговор, **как бы (будто)** и не говорил я вам ничего вовсе и **как бы ни** трудно вам это сделать.

Здесь два  однородных придаточных предложения, но они имеют разное значение  **(уподобление и  уступка)**. А разе это возможно?  Вероятно, имеет место **сближение значений**, так как оба предложения относятся **к одной ситуации** (давайте забудем…).

2. Дополнительно разберу разговорный **пример с инверсией.** Я считаю, что там можно выразить только уступительное  значение:

Мне вас **как бы ни хотЕлось** увидеть,  но что поделаешь, мы ведь не принадлежим только самим себе.

Инверсия дает возможность **выделить ударением** слово «хотелось», тем самым подчеркнув его **значимость.**

Comment: Вы предлагаете писать как бы не, но в тоже время говорите, что не трудно найти, и вообще можно сомневаться в ее существовании. Тогда зачем писать с не, если она противоречит правилам?

Comment: А вы докажите, что противоречит. Уступки здесь нет никакой, а отрицание весьма возможно. Новый участник без труда  это определил на слух.  Надо грамматику смотреть.

Comment: Перечитал ответ, но так и не понял, о чём говорит Серж. Где "вы предлагаете писать как бы не"?  Что "не трудно найти"? И в существовании чего можно сомневаться?

Comment: Это первое предложение:  Как бы (если бы) не хотел...  Я говорю о том, что хорошо бы найти в литературе эту фразу.  А Серж говорит:  если пока не нашли, так и писать нечего.

Comment: А, я не всё прочитал :). Но Серж пишет "не трудно найти", а надо было без **не**. // Первоначально, когда в вопросе не было "Дополнительного пояснения", мне казалось, что первое предложение написано с ошибкой, так как в современной речи такого не услышишь...

Comment: Я слышу это прекрасно, как будто сама так говорила когда-то)  С другой стороны, КАБЫ – это точно КАК БЫ.  Какие же еще доказательства нужны? А уступка разве туда подходит? Предложение с уступкой теряет смысл.

Comment: После пояснения и я услышал, а с КАБЫ ваще красота.

Comment: Можно еще так проверить: убрать КАК БЫ из предложения,  Тогда получится бессоюзная связь, а смысл хорошо читается: не хотел бы – так разве  бы приехал. А слово КАК БЫ нам хорошо знакомо, просто любимое слово.

Comment: @Sharon, я обратился к лингвистам Омского института. Вот что они ответили.

Comment: На самом деле вопрос не в не/ни, а в том, что это предложение грамматически некорректно. Правильно:
1) Как бы ни хотел я приехать, сделать это не удалось.
2) Если бы я хотел приехать, разве не сделал бы это при первой возможности?

Comment: И я с ними полностью согласен. Мне стоило раньше обратить на это внимание.

Comment: Передайте привет лингвистам. Они сообщили вам очевидные для всех вещи, сравнив стандартные варианты: уступка или отрицание. Мое предложение выглядит так: Кабы (если бы) не хотел я приехать, то разве поспешил бы сделать (разве не сделал бы) это при первой возможности. Я указала варианты. Но дело ваше, лингвистам Омского института надо доверять безусловно, Как сказали, значит, так и есть.

Comment: Вы у них еще про "закон озвончения" спросите, вопрос https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478580/Всегда-ли-действует-закон-озвончения Все молчат, и вы в том числе, что же это за "новое правило" такое для приставок ДИС/ДИЗ? Как его оценить, как к нему относиться? Такое впечатление, что форум негласно решили закрыть. Никто не отвечает, не комментирует, не голосует. Этимология никому не интересна, морфемный разбор никому не нужен, фонетика тем более. Раньше не было такого равнодушия ко всему.

Answer (score 2):

Очень заинтересовала эта тема, жду других ответов, но, пока их нет, попробую проверить себя.

(1) ***Как бы не** хотел я приехать, то разве поспешил бы сделать это при первой возможности.*

Я вижу здесь *как бы* в значении ***если бы***. Человек утверждает, что если бы не хотел приехать, то не поспешил бы сделать этого при первой возможности.

(2) ***Как бы ни** хотелось мне увидеть вас, но что поделаешь, мы ведь не принадлежим только самим себе.*

Выходит, что **уступительное значение**: вопреки тому, что человеку хотелось увидеться, он не может ничего поделать. Честно говоря, не могу перестать видеть тут усилительное значение частицы *ни*, но я плохо разбираюсь в терминологии. Начала писать ответ до вашей правки и теперь подстраиваю пояснения под неё.

Забавно, что мне показался возможным и другой вариант. Пожалуй, при перестановке слов лучше получится понять интонацию.

*Мне вас **как бы не** хотелось увидеть, но что поделаешь, мы ведь не принадлежим только самим себе.*

Человек вроде и не хотел увидеться, но по независимым от него причинам это произошло. Наверно, это больше разговорный вариант, однако вдруг он имеет право на жизнь. Если да, то интересно, какое тут значение. Предположительности?

(3) ***Как бы ни** сомневались вы во мне, но хотя бы на этот раз прошу вас поверить в мою искренность.*

**Уступительное значение**: несмотря на то, что кто-то сомневался в человеке, тот просит поверить ему в этот раз.

(4) ***Как бы не** пришлось мне уехать раньше, и в этом мои опасения, но я все-таки постараюсь подольше оставаться у вас.*

**Выражение опасения**: возможно, человеку придётся уехать раньше, но он постарается остаться подольше.

(5) *И давайте забудем тот разговор, **как бы и не** говорил я вам ничего вовсе и **как бы не** трудно вам это сделать.*

Думаю, тут *как бы* в значении *как будто*: смысл останется тем же, если заменить одно на другое. Таким образом, это **уподобление**.

Буду рада, когда всё разъяснит кто-нибудь более компетентный, а я смогу проверить свои догадки.

Дополнение:

Я подозревала, что пятый ответ не будет верным, но рискнула высказать такое предположение. Я посчитала, что во втором случае должно быть *как бы не* по нескольким причинам: наличие двух однородных придаточных, положение в предложении (после первого придаточного, а не в начале предложения) и отсутствие глагола *было*. Как я рассуждала. Есть два факта: человек что-то говорил (в разговоре), а другому трудно забыть тот разговор (это сделать). Человек предлагает начать отрицать оба этих факта: давайте забудем так, как будто и не говорил я вам ничего вовсе и как будто не трудно вам это сделать (забыть). Натянула сову на глобус, честно говоря. Если бы второе придаточное было в другом месте и содержало глагол *было*, я бы поставила, разумеется, частицу *ни*.

***Как бы ни** трудно вам **было** это сделать, давайте забудем тот разговор, **как бы и не** говорил я вам ничего вовсе.*

То есть: несмотря на то, что трудно вам будет это сделать, давайте забудем тот разговор. Не знаю почему, но вот без *было* не выглядело это достаточно логичным для меня. К тому же я не думала, что придаточные уступки и уподобления могут так соседствовать.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за интерес к теме и за ответ (голос от меня), в нем много правильных решений. Но давайте пока сохраним интригу и подождем другие ответы. Если их не будет, то сверим наши ответы. Меня удивило то, что в учебных материалах в Интернете два варианта обсуждаются очень часто, в то время как пользователям хорошо знакома только уступительная форма.

Comment: @Sharon, спасибо вам за любопытный вопрос! Он отчего-то зацепил меня. Стараюсь не забывать ставить голоса, потому что раньше посещала это место без регистрации. Я дополнила свой ответ пояснением, которое опустила при публикации: боюсь попасть впросак из-за неверного употребления терминов. Захотелось всё-таки объяснить этот момент. Ещё отдельное мерси за то, что вы прокомментировали мой пример с инверсией! Это было что-то по аналогии с: _я апельсины как бы не люблю, но раз уж ты мне его почистил, то давай_. Решилась всё же написать его, ну а вдруг бы кто-то, как и я, нашёл это забавным.

Answer (score 1):

В примерах 1,2,3 частица ни усиливает  утвердительный смысл придаточного предложения. Это уступительные придаточные предложения.

*1)Как бы **ни** хотел я приехать, то разве поспешил бы сделать это при первой возможности.*

*2)Как бы **ни** сомневались вы во мне, но хотя бы на этот раз прошу вас поверить в мою искренность.

*3)Как бы **ни** хотелось мне увидеть вас, но что поделаешь, мы ведь не принадлежим только самим себе.*

В примере 4, как было верно сказано, значения опасения.

Как бы **не** пришлось мне уехать раньше, и в этом мои опасения, но я все-таки постараюсь подольше оставаться у вас.

В примере 5 имеются однородные придаточные. В первой части придаточное сравнения, во второй придаточное уступительное.  Соответственно пишем пишем **не** и **ни**.

*И давайте забудем тот разговор, как бы и не говорил(**как будто бы**) я вам ничего вовсе и как бы ни трудно(**даже если было бы трудно**) вам это сделать.*

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, голос от меня.  Наши ответы не совпадают полностью. Но давайте сохраним пока интригу, а ответы сверим позже. Может, еще кто-то захочет ответить.

Comment: Ну, будем ждать.