# Всегда ли действует закон озвончения?

Tags: фонетика

В слове **"дислексия"** действует закон озвончения или нет?

Я это слово произношу с озвончением - ди[з]лексия. То же самое, например, со словом "дисморфофобия". Можно легко сказать ди[з]морфофобия.

Если же звук все-таки звонкий, то тогда на каком основании пишется "с" (в соответствии с новым правилами):

> исключение – приставка диз/дис пишется с буквой с перед несонорными
> согласными и по произношению – перед гласной, йотом и сонорными

Answer (score 1):

**Интересная история**

1. Всегда ли действует закон озвончения?  **Существует ли он вообще?** Да, существует. Это **общий** закон русской орфоэпии и орфографии, связанный с любыми **фонетическими** изменениями звуков (как гласных, так и согласных).  Такие изменения не отражаются на письме.
2. Произношение парных **звонких/глухих** согласных может изменяться перед шумными согласными (**слабая позиция**), а вот позиция перед **гласными, сонорными и йотой** считается **сильной**. Там мы слышим смысловой звук (фонему).  По этому принципу делается **проверка:** *реЗкий —  реЗать/реЗной; веСкий — веСить/равновеСный*, для чего используются **гласные или сонорные.**

**Примечание.** Такое изменение согласного звука по звонкости/глухости называется **[регрессивной ассимиляцией](https://vidstyle.ru/primery-assimilyacii-v-russkom-progressivnaya-i-regressivnaya.html)** (уподоблением), так как  последующий звук влияет на предшествующий.

3. **Наши приставки  на З/С** —  исключение из этого правила,  они пишутся по слуху. Но вот приставка ***С*** всегда пишется одинаково. Об этом тоже все знают.
4. Иноязычную приставку ***ДИС*** (греческий вариант) тоже  можно  считать приставкой **постоянного состава**, кроме исключения ***ДИЗ***. Обычно называлось слово ***дизъюнкция***, где использовался вариант на ***З***.  Школьникам этого  было более чем достаточно.
5. Для чего же потребовалось **«новое правило»?** В современном языке, кроме экзотических слов с приставкой ДИЗ, обнаружились слова, которые стали общеизвестными: ***дислексия, дислайк***. С ними-то  что делать?  У них свои правила (греческая или римская приставка), ну а мы вводим **свое правило**.
   Перед **шумными** согласными в слабой позиции будем писать ***С*** (там могут быть оба звука), а в сильной позиции (перед сонорными и гласными)  пишем **смысловой звук** как он есть.
6. Но мы уже привыкли видеть букву ***З***  перед сонорной ***Л*** в русских приставках (***разлил, взлетел, изломал***), поэтому нам по аналогии более привычно написание и произношение "дизлексия",  в то же время "***сломал***" мы тоже легко произносим. Позиция звука перед Л свободная (сильная).
7. Поэтому надо **перестраиваться**, а пока следует проверять такие (новые) слова с приставкой ДИС/ДИЗ по словарю, причем **и написание, и произношение.**Если ж после приставки стоит шумны согласный, то по основному правилу пишем ***ДИС***.
8. ***Дисморфофобия?***  Тоже проверяем перед сонорной ***М***.  А это другие слова (спец.) с приставкой ***ДИС/ДИЗ:*** *дизартрия, диссоциация, дизассемблер и дисассемблер, дизруптивный.*

**ВЫВОД** ("закон озвончения")

Если в **сильной** позиции звука (перед гласной, сонорной или йотой) вы озвончаете букву С, указанную **в словаре**, то вы неправильно произносите это слово.
Проверять произношение необязательно, достаточно **орфографического** словаря.

В качестве **версии**

Почему было принято "новое правило"? Как я думаю, это связано с нежеланием менять форму ***ДИС*** для **общеупотребительных слов**. В настоящий момент форма ***ДИЗ*** возможна преимущественно в специальной лексике, и там нужен контроль по словарю. Если слово становится привычным, то там пишется и произносится ***ДИС*** **по общему правилу.**

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не всегда (действует закон - да и закон ли он?).

"Дислексия" слышится, как пишется, на обновлённой Грамоте ввели произношение, [кликнуть по рупору](https://gramota.ru/meta/disleksiya):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хорошо ориентироваться с диз/дис позволяет [сайт](https://oross.ruslang.ru/orthogr/formula?id=33), откуда и взяты исключения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это про то, как пишется. А как слышится - это другое, регрессивная ассимиляция называется (Ваше озвончение идёт по ней): последующий звонкий согласный озвончает предшествующий глухой: здоба, зделка, зборник... о, [целую поэму нашла о типах ассимиляции](https://www.izbornik.ru/theory/phonetics/about_sounds).

Для справки:

> В русском литературном языке прогрессивная ассимиляция практически не
> встречается, но примеры этого явления можно найти в диалектной речи:
> Танька — [та́н'к'а(ъ)].